# Asp.Net Identity Usermanager and Unit Of Work - how to mate them?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am using the Unit Of Work Pattern and have defined a class for it in a separate sub-project called MyProject.Domain.DAL.UnitOfWork.

Unfortunately, the whole ASP.Net Identity infrastructure is in my main project (as in the tutorial), MyProject.

Even more problematic: As I understand it, the ASP.NET identity uses it's own DBContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ApplicationDbContext"/> class, using the EFDB context.
    /// </summary>
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("EFDBContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A database context</returns>
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I have a class called Project, which should have a user associated with it - but how to do that, without using conflicting db contexts?

Example:

```
public class Project
{
   public ApplicationUser User {get; set;}
}
```

Example calling code:

```
public class IndexController : Controller
{
    // uow and userManager are instantiated through Ninject
    // example code, normally this would be properties of the controller
    public ActionResult Create(IUnitOfWork uow, ApplicationUserManager userManager, int someID )
    {
       Project newProject = new Project(); 
       ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(someID);
       // this should give a conflict, since two different DataContexts are involved
       newProject.User = user;
       uow.Projects.Insert(newProject);
       uow.Save()
       return this.View();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is a bit confusing. You shouldn't create a separate own `DbContext` but rather extend the existing `ApplicationDbContext` with the rest of the data model. You can move it to somewhere else in the project, as long as you change the type in `IdentityConfig.cs`.

There is a tougher problem to solve though when using unit of work and it is that the ASP.NET Identity methods call `SaveChanges()` internally and when using unit of work you typically only want that once all the work is done. A workaround could be to use a `TransactionScope()` but it could be messy to get it created before the per-request DbContext that ASP.NET Identity uses.

Comment: The advice about the DbContext was great, I struggled with that moments ago....

The other problem is indeed grave... I have no idea how to solve that fluently. I really dislike Asp.net Identity, full of half assed ideas